# Customize jBPM KIE Workbench Home Page

Tags: jbpm

I am using jbpm 6.2 and want to customize the KIE Workbench Homepage. By customize i mean, i would like to update the layout, color theme and css. Highly appreciate any guidance.

Regards,

Arsalan.

Comment: Have you tried to look inside the `lib` folder inside the `jbpm-installer`? There's a `war` file named `dashboard-builder-6.2.0.Final-wildfly-8.1.0.Final.war`. I was able to find the `index.jsp` and `login.jsp` pages that I think refer to the login page and index page of the KIE workbench, respectively. I'm not so sure of the answer myself, but hopefully this might help to get your started to customize the KIE homepage.

Answer (score 0):

As jl987 said, you want to look in `jbpm-installer\lib\jbpm-console-6.2.0.Final-wildfly-8.1.0.Final.war` archive.

Then you can modify the files you need - `login.jsp` etc.